# Keep alive view-router by key param

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

How do I keep vue-router alive with different params separately?

**TL:DR**:

Let's consider an example when we're developing a website like facebook. Each user has a profile page. Because there are a lot of users we don't want to iterate all users and load all profile page on load like bellow

```
<template v-for="profile in profilePages">
   <profile-page :data="profile" v-show="this.route.params['id'] === channel.id"/>
</template>
```

The common approach would be:

**router.js**:

```
{
  component: ProfileWrapper,
  path: '/profile',
  children: [
    {
      path: ':id',
      component: ProfilePage
    }
  ]
}
```

**ChannelsPage**:

```
<keep-alive>
   <router-view :=key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
</keep-alive>
```

But here's the issue. Since user visits someone's page and navigates away, I want the router to keep it alive in cache somewhere, or just hide it. In my particular case, user visits 2-3 profile at most and switches a lot between them. And switching operation is time costly, because there are a lot of DOM in it.

Can I do it with **vue-router** and **keep-alive**?

**EDIT**:

Please check the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xo0kokomyz). Each time you switch between pages (#1,#2,#3,#4) `Vue` creates new components `ProfileInnerComponent` from the scratch (not from the cache like v-show). That's noticeably by checking red div, the `create` hook of `ProfileInnerComponent` is called, which emits the event, and `App` adds the div with current time.

Comment: A better example case, to understand what you want?I am sorry but i don't understand

Comment: @roliroli please check the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xo0kokomyz), There's a console tab right at the bottom, please open it. While it's open switch between pages (#1,#2,#3,#4). You will find `Some component created again time ??` messages appear in console, which means vue rerenders page each time I switch it

Answer (score 3):

In order this to work you need unique names on your components, which you would then use the `include` property on `<keep-alive>`.

```
<keep-alive include="Foo,Bar">
  ...
</keep-alive>
```

In you case, you would be better served using dynamic components rather than a single route.

```
<component :is="$route.params.id"></component>
```

[keep-alive with Dynamic Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components)

[keep-alive API reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive)

**update**

Pre-fetching channel content based on the query param id:

```
// routes.js
routes = [
  {
    path: '/channel/:id',
    name: 'show.channel',
    props: true,
    component: Channel
  }
  ...
]

// Channel.vue
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      content: ''
    }
  }
  beforeRouteEnter(to,from,next) {
    axios.get('/api/channel/' + to.params.id).then(response => {
      next(vm => {
        vm.content = reponse.data
      })
    })
  },
  watch: {
    '$route' (to, from) {
      // fetch new channel content when a query param is changed.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Let's consider each `Channel` component as database entity, where `:id` is its identified. So a user can add new channel in runtime.  All the channel have the same structure, how and why I create separate components for them? Furthermore, I don't know amount of them.

Comment: In that case, you would only need one component, let's just say `Channel`. To access a specific channel you'd need a route like `/channel/:id`. Then the channel's content could be pre-fetched using the `beforeRouteEnter` navigation guard. The docs [here contain examples](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards)

Comment: This still doesn't solve the issue that on navigating between `channels` Vue would re-render the whole thing all over again, does it? By re-rendering I don't mean doing XHR request, I mean recreating dom structure. The issue is that component `Channel` is vast, some of its parts using native html rendering (yes, I'm aware of runtime template compile, there's no a case) and it's time-costly to re-create it from the scratch. That's why I want it lazy.

Comment: If you use `watch: { '$route' }` it should reuse the component. Or use the `beforeRouteUpdate` lifecycle hook, both of which will not recreate the entire component. Docs [here explain further](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes)

Comment: I really bad at explaining I guess, the structure of `Channel` is the same, but the content is different, `channel#1` may contain 100 elements in loop, `channel#2` may contain 1000 elements in loop, while the structure is predefined, the dom content depends on remote `API`. If I watch the `route`, only the static things on the `channel` page would remain the same, while things like loops would rerender.

Comment: Ok I follow, but unfortunately I don't believe it's possible to cache dynamically loaded content in this way using only the vue framework. If there is then I'm unaware. The best alternative I can think of would be to store the api results in localStorage or something client side to limit the number of api requests between channels.

Comment: Ok I guess I'll do some ugly loop template with `v-show` + `v-if="isInited"`

Answer (score 3):

I changed your sandbox by adding this codes:

```
// in App.vue

<keep-alive>
   <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
</keep-alive>
```

and

```
//in Profile.vue

  <keep-alive>
    <profile-inner-component v-for="i in comps" :key="i" :data="i"/>
  </keep-alive>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understand correctly but lets suppose you have 2 pages.

Admins and Users and each page has an `counter` which is initially 0.

So you want when you are in Admins page and you increasing the counter,when navigating to another page and return back to Admins page the counter to be as you have left it.

I made a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zxj76rmz7x) for this.Also please keep open the console to see how many times the components is rendered.

**NOTE** that in the sandbox example,is illustrated the logic how to achieve this.Never use keep-alive in `router-view` in `App.vue`.

Comment: Please check my [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xo0kokomyz). Suppose you're developing website like facebook, so each user has his/her page. You don't know each user id, and each user page has thousand nodes (like DIVs). Each user can navigate through other user pages, and the `page` is a vue component. It's not like userA has `A.vue` and userB has `B.vue`, all pages use `Common.vue` with `:id` param. Now when user visits `pageA`, then `pageB` and then `pageA` , `pageA` should render from cache (or something like v-show). In my sandbox `Channel.vue` renders from scratch upon visit

Comment: Yes, and in this sandbox provided in my answer,it is not rerendered.You can check it

Comment: Your sandbox have different pages, that are cached by name. My sandbox is a single page `Channel.vue` that can be loaded with different ':id' parameter, that's the difference I tried to explained