# keep-alive doesn't cache component

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have issue with having `keep-alive` actually keeping components alive.

Component that is being rendered in router-view have async fetching after component is mounted. My issue is that after the first time component shows up, when I render other component in that very same router, and then go back, then first component rerender as normal instead of keeping fetched data as it was.

I checked hooks and besides `activated` and `deactivated` also `created` hook fires which I suppose shouldn't be the case beyond first render. Also when I switch components `destroyed` hook fires which also shouldn't happen.

```
.container-fluid
  .row.wrapper
    aside.col-12.col-sm-2.p-0
      nav.navbar.navbar-light.navbar-expand-sm.align-items-start.flex-sm-column.flex-row.text-uppercase#navbar1
        a.navbar-toggler(href='', data-toggle='collapse', data-target='.sidebar')
          span.navbar-toggler-icon
        .collapse.navbar-collapse.sidebar
          ul.flex-column.navbar-nav.w-100.justify-content-between
            li.nav-item
              router-link.nav-link.pl-0(to='candidates' data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show")
                font-awesome-icon.fa-fw.mr-2(:icon="iconTachometer")
                | Dashboard  

    main.col.bg-faded.py-3
      .card
        .card-body
          keep-alive
            router-view(:key="$route.fullPath")
```

Comment: you cannot `keep alive` functional components - btw duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40898440/vue-2-keep-alive-not-working-with-router-view-and-key, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51116961/keep-alive-view-router-by-key-param

Comment: @Estradiaz it's not a functional component. It's a normal one that fetches data when it mounts.

Comment: ok was sure its states true: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/c3abdf6baf924b621627c0d14645ab344ce1189d/src/components/view.js#L6 - but nvm must be an optical illusion ;)

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive just at the end there is a note: `<keep-alive> does not work with functional components because they do not have instances to be cached.` So despite being functional it works on with non-functional (as far as I read).

Comment: yes but as long as you use it like keep-alive \n router-view it wont

Comment: The problem is that people are already doing that: https://itnext.io/yes-this-is-how-to-cache-pages-by-url-with-vue-vue-router-and-keep-alive-component-697ed76896e8 example from this page: https://jsfiddle.net/darkylmnx/ey9acx1z/31 but it doesn't seem to work with my case

Comment: you are right - i will read keep-alive again to get a bit of insight - https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/52719ccab8fccffbdf497b96d3731dc86f04c1ce/src/core/components/keep-alive.js

Comment: @Estradiaz I found the solution! Please see answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the answer - and my apologies because turned out my question wasn't fully informed.

First thing - the component in question was already nested within another `router-view` so what I was actually doing was nesting one in another.

Therefore, to keep alive that nested/child `router-view` parent `router-view` also has to be wrapped with `keep-alive`.

Based on answer here: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-use-keep-alive-with-nested-router-component/46813/4

Comment: Link broken I stuck many day till now, about nest router-view one with another, I am using Vue3

Answer (score 0):

See [Special Attributes - key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key):

> It can also be used to force replacement of an element/component
> instead of reusing it. This can be useful when you want to:
>
> 1. Properly trigger lifecycle hooks of a component;
> 2. Trigger transitions.

If you bind `key` to `$route.fullPath`, it will always **force a replacement** of the `<router-view>` element / component every time a navigation event occurs. So just remove `:key`.